# How to get values from a complex array in a loop using PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the list of all stripe subscribers on my PHP page.

I have managed to get the details of 1 subscriber from the array that's returned from stripe API so far.

But when I try to get the details of 2 or 3 etc subscribers, I get nothing.

I know I will need to use a loop or for each to achieve this but I can't figure out how.

This is my current code to get the details of 1 subscriber:

```
$data = \Stripe\Subscription::all(['limit' => 1]);

$sub_id = $data->data[0]->id;

echo $sub_id;
```

Now I need to get the details of more than 1 subscriber so I tried this which didn't work and doesn't return anything (no errors either):

```
 $data = \Stripe\Subscription::all(['limit' => 2]);

foreach ($data as $k => $v) { 

echo $data->data[0]->id;


}
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: When do you use `$v` in your foreach loop ? By the way you should probably dump us the structure of your `$data` - Not everybody is familiar with the library you're using.

Comment: @Altherius, nowhere.. i thought about removing that and just have `foreach ($data as $k) { ..}` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you give the output of `var_dump($data)` in your question please ? Would certainly help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to loop `$data->data` as it is an array of objects and then access the `id` property of each object:

```
foreach ($data->data as $v) { 
    echo $v->id;
}
```